# Nginx - failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Im working in local. I have 2 containers in docker:

[image]

I have two nginx images. One with this .conf:

[image]

an another:

[image]

When i run the reverse_proxy to redirect to the other container, i recive:

[image]

Comment: Maybe the first container is looking for port 80 inside itself rather than routing the packets to the other container, or to the host.

Comment: Hi!, the first container is listen on port 81, and redirect with the proxy_pass to localhost at port 80

Comment: Use the [debug log](http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html) to find out what exactly happens.

Comment: I dont find anything relevant :(

Comment: Debug log contains everything that nginX performs - it will definitely show why you see 502 status code.

Comment: I solved the problem by modifying the value in the proxy pass. It had to point to the container hostname, not to localhost.

In the nginx.conf at the first container:
proxy_pass http://172.17.0.1:8082;

Comment: So my assumption was right - `localhost` referred to the first container itself rather than to the other container :)

Comment: Yes, hanks for answering!